# In Python, how to convert a hexadecimal number to its corresponding unicode character?

Tags: python, unicode

I want to convert a hexadecimal number such as '0x0391' to its corresponding Unicode character (in this example is the Greek letter A). I have tried to concat the four hexadecimal digits (stored in a variable h) to the end of "\u", like "\u"+h or f"\u{h}". Both attempts produced an error. It seems that python will check the escape character before substitute the values in the f-string. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Which encoding?

Comment: @JoranBeasley: It's [GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ALPHA](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0391/index.htm).

Answer (score 3):

If you have the number available as a string, parse it and pass it to [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=chr#chr):

```
> chr(int('0x0391', base=16))
'Α'
```